# HTML5 audio player not working on playlist

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I have an HTML5 audio player, it is simple coded with JavaScript.
It's working fine on a single audio. But the problem is here when I'm adding more audios the only the first one is working and the remaining were not.
Check it out of [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8dzd6bh4/5/)
**HTML**

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <audio id="yourAudio" preload='none'>
       <source src='http://freshly-ground.com/data/audio/mpc/20090119%20-%20Untitled%20Groove.mp3' type='audio/mpeg' />
    </audio>
    <a href="#"  ><span id="audioControl" class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></span></a>
    <audio id="yourAudio" preload='none'>
       <source src='http://audio.khanqah.org/AK20021104%20Rozay%20or%20taqwa%20may%20rabt.mp3' type='audio/mpeg' />
    </audio>
    <a href="#"  ><span id="audioControl" class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></span></a>

    <audio id="yourAudio" preload='none'>
       <source src='http://audio.khanqah.org/AK19991224%20Tark%20e%20masiat%20may%20takheer%20na%20kijiay.mp3' type='audio/mpeg' />
    </audio>
    <a href="#"  ><span id="audioControl" class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"></span></a>
```

**Js**

```
var yourAudio = document.getElementById('yourAudio'),
    ctrl = document.getElementById('audioControl');

ctrl.onclick = function () {


if(ctrl.className == "glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle") {
        ctrl.className="glyphicon glyphicon-pause";
       yourAudio["play"]();
}
else if (ctrl.className == "glyphicon glyphicon-pause"){

     ctrl.className="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle";
    yourAudio["pause"]();

}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed your HTML code so the audio tags are inside a div called playList.

```
<div id="playList">
<a href="#">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle">
        <audio preload='none'>
            <source src='http://freshly-ground.com/data/audio/mpc/20090119%20-%20Untitled%20Groove.mp3' type='audio/mpeg' />
        </audio>
    </span>
</a>
<a href="#">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle">
        <audio preload='none'>
            <source src='http://audio.khanqah.org/AK20021104%20Rozay%20or%20taqwa%20may%20rabt.mp3' type='audio/mpeg' />
        </audio>
    </span>
</a>
<a href="#">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle">
        <audio preload='none'>
            <source src='http://audio.khanqah.org/AK19991224%20Tark%20e%20masiat%20may%20takheer%20na%20kijiay.mp3' type='audio/mpeg' />
        </audio>
    </span>
</a>
</div>
```

Then you can use event delegation to play or pause your audio sources

```
document.getElementById('playList').addEventListener('click', function(e){
var target = e.target;
if(target && target.nodeName === 'SPAN'){
    if(target.className == "glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"){
        target.childNodes[1]['play']();
        target.className = "glyphicon glyphicon-pause"
    }else{
        target.childNodes[1]['pause']();
        target.className = "glyphicon glyphicon-play-circle"
    }
}});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/8dzd6bh4/20/) you have a working demo

Comment: That's great, But if you noticed when you play an audio and then another audio both will playing I need when I click on 1st audio and then 2nd audio 1st will pause/stop.

Comment: You may create a function that pause all the audio tags on the playlist.