# Buttons click Sounds

Tags: jquery, html, html5-audio

This is what I wanna do:

I have like 30 buttons. And I want that when click each button, it will play different mp3 file. Like this http://www.soundjig.com/pages/soundfx/beeps.html

I just know how to click 1 button to play 1 audio file like this:

```
<audio id="mysoundclip" preload="auto">
   <source src="ci1.mp3"></source>
</audio>
<button type="button" class="ci">play</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var audio = $("#mysoundclip")[0];
      console.log(audio);
  $("button.play").click(function() {
      audio.play();
  });
</script>
```

I don't wanna apply all this code to all of the buttons - Is there anyway to do this quickly?

Thank you for reading!

Comment: I just answered this question on another thread, is this homework? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31715188/buttons-click-sounds

Comment: @FelixG same post, here is the [correct link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31715017/html5-audio-player-not-working-on-playlist/31715260#31715260)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `Audio` class provided by JavaScript.

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/1gt1Lzr6/5/).

Here is the snippet.

```js
var baseUrl = "http://www.soundjay.com/button/";
var audio = ["beep-01a.mp3", "beep-02.mp3", "beep-03.mp3", "beep-04.mp3", "beep-05.mp3", "beep-06.mp3", "beep-07.mp3", "beep-08b.mp3", "beep-09.mp3"];

$('button.ci').click(function() {
  var i = $(this).attr('id').substring(1);           //get the index of button
  new Audio(baseUrl + audio[i - 1]).play();          //play corresponding audio
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="b1" type="button" class="ci">SOUND</button>
<br>
<button id="b2" type="button" class="ci">SOUND</button>
<br>
<button id="b3" type="button" class="ci">SOUND</button>
<br>
<button id="b4" type="button" class="ci">SOUND</button>
<br>
<button id="b5" type="button" class="ci">SOUND</button>
<br>
<button id="b6" type="button" class="ci">SOUND</button>
<br>
<button id="b7" type="button" class="ci">SOUND</button>
<br>
<button id="b8" type="button" class="ci">SOUND</button>
<br>
<button id="b9" type="button" class="ci">SOUND</button>
<br>
```

Comment: I mean each button will play an different sound.
Is this work as what I mean?
Thank you!

Comment: Updated my answer. If you have the list of audio files, then the answer will help you

Comment: Now it makes sense since OP knows already how to implement solution for one button and he needed to handle all his buttons

Answer (score 0):

Make your buttons different from each other by adding an `id` to each of them. This will allow you to map each button with its own audio file by giving the same `id` to `<source>` tag. Example:

```
<audio id="mysoundclip" preload="auto">
   <source src="ci1.mp3" id="1"></source>
</audio>
<button type="button" class="ci" id="1">play</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("button.play").click(function() {
  var id = $('this').data('id');

  var audio = $('#mysoudclip #'+id)[0];
      audio.play();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: you should avoid starting `id` with number

Comment: @Kaiido, I agree with you, he can concatenate to a small string and add the logic that will handle the difference. I am editing to take into consideration the best practice you mentionned thanks

Comment: or use an array and for-loop

Comment: I used yours and turn it into:
    var audio = new Audio("file/" +id+".mp3");
Can I ask something: What if I have both mp3 and wav file, how can it recorgnize the file?

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution based on clues of Shrinivas Shukla and whiteletter (below).
And this code play both *wav and *mp3 file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('td.bb').click(function() { // add a same class to every button
    var fileName = $(this).attr('id'); //fileName as id button
    var audiot = new Audio("file/" +fileName+".mp3");
    audiot.play();
    var audiott = new Audio("file/" +fileName+".wav");
    audiott.play();
});
```

Notice: Name the sound file as id of each button that I have and add a same class to every button - in this case: "bb"

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var obj = document.createElement("audio");
  obj.src = "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/codeskulptor-assets/week7-brrring.m4a";
  obj.volume = 0.1;
  obj.autoPlay = false;
  obj.preLoad = true;
  obj.controls = true;

  $(".playSound").click(function() {
    obj.play();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="playSound">Play</button>
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does so that other users can better understand your answer.